# iOS - System sounds not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, system-sounds

I'm using system sound for a kind of notification to my users in an app. Previously, it was working as it should be. I was using

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1009);
```

I get the codes from [this site](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) and choose 1009. Later, it stopped working, not playing sounds when it should do. I checked and saw that I should use this:

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(theSoundID, ^{
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(theSoundID);
    });
```

I used this with 1009 and not worked. I reorganised it as:

```
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received3.caf"]; //filename can include extension e.g. @"bang.wav"
    if (fileURL)
    {
        SystemSoundID theSoundID;
        OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &theSoundID);
        if (error == kAudioServicesNoError)
        {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(theSoundID, ^{
                AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(theSoundID);
            });
        }
    }
```

Still, not working. (I checked whether the file exists or not, it exists. I also check if the phone is in silent mode or not, it is not)
However, in the runtime I go to Settings>Sounds and play with Ringer and Alerts volume level. Then I continue (not restart) using app and it plays sounds. After stopping and running again, error starts again. Even while getting sounds, it does not work continuously.

It might be about iOS10, I don't know. What should I do? Thank you!

Ps: I included `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting `AVAudioSession`'s category

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback  error:&err];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1009);
```

Comment: does any other system sound working? or Only problem with 1009?

Comment: No, i tried other codes and saw that it does not matter.

Comment: the above code is perfectly works for me! I think you have issues not with Code.

Comment: please let me know about last changes with audio playing

Comment: are you running on simulator?

Comment: No, i'm running my app on both iPad and phone (6 and 5s). All the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146724/discussion-between-lal-krishna-and-anyname).

Comment: I found the problem. You're right, it's not about my code. It's because we use mumble ptt on our app and it keeps sound system. Still, thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)